# How do I add command suggestion to Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was playing around with another Discord bot this morning when I accidentally use "/" as a prefix for another bot. However, Groovy popped up its command suggestion even its prefix was not "/" (I set its prefix to "-"). I'm pretty sure that this is a new Discord feature, and I don't see any other bots have this feature yet as the time I'm posting this question.

[Here is the picture of example I was talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieYmp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature called "slash commands". You can read about it here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands